# Django raw SQL queries with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Exhibit(models.Model):
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

**create.sql (PostgreSQL)**

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    surname varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Exhibit (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    author_id int NOT NULL,
    title varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Those are my simplified models(that map one to one with database tables), and I'm performing a raw query that looks like that

```
Exhibit.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM Exhibit WHERE author_id = 1")
```

In result, I get a ValueError - Cannot assign "1": "Exhibit.author_id" must be a "Author" instance.

Is there a way to solve that problem without using ORM and Author.objects(and similar stuff) at all, just by querying into database?

Comment: For a simple query like this, why not use the ORM? (i.e., `Author.objects.get(id=1).exhibit_set.all()`).

Comment: Well, I'd love to use ORM, but it's a project with some constraints, and that's one of them - do not use ORM.

Comment: do you see solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [django.db.connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) for this:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Exhibit WHERE author_id = 1")
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I still have to map the answer to the model, and since it seems to be tedious I wanted to avoid doing that manually, is there a way?

Comment: You a looking for method without using ORMs and want to get ORM mapped object, which is contraversial...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the ORM sql query, maybe this helps

```
x = Exhibit.objects.filter(author_id=x)
print x.query


#check-up
x2=Exhibit.objects.raw(str(x.query))
```

Comment: I wrote in the question asking for a method without using ORM, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: @MWaw: But the above answer helps you to see how the query should be....